# Ensure only groups are assigned to roles in GCP

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I have a requirement to ensure that only groups are assigned IAM roles. My org setup wants to enforce security practice such that users should get assigned to IAM roles only via groups and not directly.
I researched on this and found that there are no constraints like this and custom constraints currently do not support IAM resources.

I tried organization policies and right now no support for custom constraints for this.